# Using header files from sub-folder

Tags: arduino, include, arduino-ide

The Arduino IDE is having trouble including my header files, and I'm not exactly sure why.

Here's my project structure:

```
project/
 ├ project.ino
 ├ README.md
 └ src/
    └ foo.h
```

Then I have the following in my `project.ino` file:

```
#include "src/foo.h"

void init() {
    // init stuff
}

void loop() {
    // loop stuff
}
```

When I then try to compile I get the following error:

```
fatal error: src/foo.h: No such file or directory
```

Do I really have to have all my project files in the same folder?

I don't want to put the files in `library/` as the whole project is supposed to be pulled from GitHub, so having it in the same root folder is more convenient.

What am I doing wrong here, why can't it find my file?

PS: writing `#include "./src/foo.h"` does nothing to fix this

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows it should be like

```
include "src\foo.h"
```

For Windows you should use forward slash whereas background slash for Unix based systems(Mac/Linux)

Comment: I'm not using windows

Answer (score 0):

If you're using windows, use

`#include ".\\src\\foo.h"`

for Linux and MacOS, use

```
#include ".//src//foo.h"
```

The reason for Arduino's strange behavior is that .ino files are preprocessed and are copied to a temporary directory along with other libraries and .cpp & .h files. Arduino software copy these files to temporary directory but it does not copy folders.